# How start Xpad and viber minimised in the system tray when OS start. 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, system-tray

after this

Code:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

i have system tray in 14.04 LTS. 
Skype have menu item - "Start Skype minimised in the system tray" and it's work prefect.
But viber and xpad don't have this.

I install alltray. But it don't work. I can't launch viber with alltray options becouse command to start look like

```
/opt/viber/Viber
```

xpad start minimised but in tray i have two icon's and they buggy.

Comment: Hi Дмитрий Фрай, just ran into your question, missed it earlier. Let me know if the link works for you (please @ping me in a comment). Tested on al least Xpad, it works fine. (second script, since the `xpad` window has no name)

Answer (score 1):

**For Viber**, run the app with `StartMinimized` parameter.

```
/opt/viber/Viber StartMinimized
```